# Node email-templates include font files (woff / ttf)

Tags: node.js, ejs, email-templates

I'm using the node package **email-templates** which uses **juice** to inline styles and generate html output to send via email.Everything works like a charm except that I'm unable to include my font files my css is looking for.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I think you cannot send them. Better use web safe fonts in templates.